# How can I create shared std::vector<std::string> using mmap?

Tags: c++, string, vector, shared-memory, mmap

In my program, I create some child proccesses using fork and I want to share std::vector between their.
I know about mmap and I try to use my own allocator, which use mmap.

My allocator class here:
https://gist.github.com/ADKosm/798bf4caebbc5e087d86

If I create `vector<int>` with this allocator: `std::vector<int, mmap_allocator<int> >` - all proccesses can manipulate this signle copy of vector.

But if i try to use `std::vector<std::string, mmap_allocator<std::string> >` - each proccess has access only to it copy of container.

I also try to use

```
#define shared_string std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, mmap_allocator<char> >
std::vector<shared_string, mmap_allocator<shared_string> >
```

but it also doesn't work.

How can I share this container between forked proccesses?

PS. sorry for mistakes - I am just learning English language

Comment: `std::string` also allocates internal buffer which doesn't use your mmap_allocator. So you probably need to define `string` with your type of allocator. But I am not sure `std::string` supports it. I have never tried it. You need to read `std::string` constructor documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide your allocator to std::string as well. Since std::string is a typedef for std::basic_string, you'd actually to have to use `std::basic_string<char, mmap_allocator<char> >`.